# Adding filters to mustachejs

Tags: javascript, filter, mustache, hogan.js

I am working with expresshogan and want to add filters to my mustache variables and to change as little to my code as possible and haven't found any solutions

My Code currently looks like this:

```
        <tbody>
          {{#totals}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ source_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ date_published }}</td>
            <td><a href = "{{ url }}" target="_blank">link</a></td>
          </tr>
          {{/totals}}
        </tbody>
```

I would like to implement a solution similar to this:

```
       <label>Filter</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
         <hr>      

          <tbody>
          {{#totals|yourName}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ source_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ date_published }}</td>
            <td><a href = "{{ url }}" target="_blank">link</a></td>
          </tr>
          {{/totals}}
        </tbody>
```

I have angular working with %% %% brackets I would like to filter based on user input on the front end only.

Angular does this really nicely but I cant seem to find a solution for mustache anywhere!

Comment: Mustache does not support filters. Handlebars.js does.

Comment: So after much work and research to my dismay it is impossible to dynamically filter in hogan/mustache. My solution is to get and post within express, get user input filter and resend an http to the new page. If any one comes upon this question in my situation my solution is not fast or efficient or pretty it is micky moused but sometimes you have to do what you have to do. This also works well since I am outputting to a text view and a D3 like view so this way, i am filtering at one point so my views will be identical ** if anyone is curious about this ask and i will post my code